# PathGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail() always returns IntersectionDetail.Empty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, path, intersection

Following code always gets to IntersectionDetail.Empty, but should also get to FullyContains or FullyInside. Why?

```
Path p1; // filled with a polygon
Path p2; // filled with another polygon

PathGeometry pg1 = p1.RenderedGeometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry().GetWidenedPathGeometry(new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(), 1)).GetOutlinedPathGeometry(1, ToleranceType.Absolute);
pg1.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd;

PathGeometry pg2 = p2.RenderedGeometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry().GetWidenedPathGeometry(new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(), 1)).GetOutlinedPathGeometry(1, ToleranceType.Absolute);
pg2.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd;

IntersectionDetail id = pg1.FillContainsWithDetail(pg2);
if (id == IntersectionDetail.FullyContains) // never reached but should
if (id == IntersectionDetail.FullyInside) //never reached but should
if (id == IntersectionDetail.Intersect) // always reached (edit: found a bug no more the error case)
if (id == IntersectionDetail.Empty) // edit: after bug fix now always reached
```

The polygons are drawn to screen, so I can say this should really get to the cases FullyContains/FullyInside.
Any ideas to get this working?

Edit: Solved by myself, see answer below.

Comment: Have you put `pg1` and `pg2` into two other Paths controls and visually checked them too?

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to find a bug. I forgot to set the `StartPoint`, `IsClosed = true` and `IsFilled = true` of the `PathFigure`. But now I get `IntersectionDetail.Empty` and no FullyInside/FullyContains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that GetWidenedPathGeometry and GetOutlinedPathGeometry manipulate the PathGeometry in a way, that the intersection gets empty. After removing these and just call GetFlattenedPathGeometry makes my code to run fine as expected.

Here is the fixed code:

```
Path p1; // filled with a polygon
Path p2; // filled with another polygon

PathGeometry pg1 = p1.RenderedGeometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
pg1.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd;

PathGeometry pg2 = p2.RenderedGeometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
pg2.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd;

IntersectionDetail id = pg1.FillContainsWithDetail(pg2);
if (id == IntersectionDetail.FullyContains) // now reached as expected
if (id == IntersectionDetail.FullyInside) // now reached as expected
if (id == IntersectionDetail.Intersect)
if (id == IntersectionDetail.Empty)
```

Comment: I am trying the same thing with 2 Ellipse objects drawn in a canvas. I always get Intersects. Any idea?